# CodeIgniter - keep data in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, static

Basically, what I have is something like :

```
class Database extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function connect($connection_infos)
    {
        $db = @new mysqli($connection_infos['host'], $connection_infos['username'],
                $connection_infos['password'], $connection_infos['database']);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            return FALSE;
        else
            return TRUE;
    }
}
```

This model is loaded in a controller's function :

```
class Management extends CI_Controller
{

    static $dbs = array(
                'ref' => array(
                    'connected' => FALSE,
                ),
                'dest' => array(
                    'connected' => FALSE,
                )
            );

    function connection()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $data = array();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('host', 'Hostname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('database', 'Database', 'required');
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data['dbs'] = self::$dbs;
        } else {
            $this->load->model('database'); // Here I load the model
            $connection_infos = array(
                    'host' => $this->input->post('host'),
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                    'database' => $this->input->post('database'),
                );
            if ($this->database->connect($connection_infos)) {
                self::$dbs['ref']['connected'] = TRUE;
                $data['dbs'] = self::$dbs;
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
    }
}
```

So here is what I did :

On the form validation in my view, I call the function `connection` from my Controller. This function loads the `Database` model, and calls the function `connect` of the model.

My question is : If I want to make others functions in my model that make others requests, will I be forced to open a connection at each time ? If yes, how can I "store" the connection credentials ?

Thanks !

Comment: You are aware the Codeigniter does have a Database helper library right? Of which you can make a custom model(s) with all the functions and requests you could ever want to reuse, and not have to worry about making your own database class, or worry about it connecting when you need it to etc..

Comment: I have a question , Why are you using Codeignitor ?

Comment: @chris of course I am, but here I want to connect dynamically to a db, depending on what the users put in a form.

Comment: @Garbage it's a light and powerful framework, easy to learn and use.

Comment: Is this a one time set up ? like the beginning of the app ,then you can `open` the `database.php` config file and set up directly,otherways  you need to tweak the DB class a little currently the connection is reading from the `config` array ,instead of that read settings FROM DB and use it.

Comment: I need both. I have my db set up in the `database.php` file, and I also need to allow the user to connect to his db and see its content (just like a phpMyAdmin system)

Answer (score 3):

Based on what I see, you need to take a trip to the CI Documentation and read up a *lot* on the [database library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html).

Beyond the basic syntax/semantics that are covered in the tutorial, a model named "Database" is illogical and not a great naming choice. In the scope of CodeIgniter, you should try to make a model only relate specifically to one database table.

As for the actual database connection, it's handled automatically in the CI_Model class as a member object, `$db`. I would suggest reading the docs on [models](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html), and [database connections](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html) in CI.

So when you have everything set up correctly, loading a correctly coded model will give you an automatic database connection within a model that can be reused however and whenever you want.

Comment: I know all this stuff, but here I would like to connect dynamically to a db using the credentials the user put in a form.